# Dynamic DataTable component not rendering after adding columns and rows in the backing bean

Tags: binding, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to create a file upload screen for a CSV file that will give the user a preview of the contents uploaded.

I have jsf tags as follows for the front end:

```
<p:fileUpload id="selectFile" value="#fileUploadBean.file}" mode="simple"/>
<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{fileUploadBean.uploadDataFile}" />
<h:panelGrid id="filePreview" binding="#{fileUploadBean.filePreview}"/>
```

On the back end, I have methods to build up the preview when the file is uploaded:

```
public String uploadDataFile() {
  createFilePreview();
  return "";
}

private void createFilePreview() {
  HtmlPanelGrid dataPrevGrid = new HtmlPanelGrid();
  dataPrevGrid.setColumns(numColumns);
    for (/*loops through all lines in the CSV file*/) {
      String row = it.next(); //get next line in CSV file
      String[] cells = row.split(",");
      for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        String cell = cells[i];
        HtmlOutputText jcell = createHtmlOutputText(cell);
        dataPrevGrid.getChildren().add(jcell);
      }
    }
}

public HtmlPanelGrid getFilePreview() {
    return filePreview;
}
```

The code all runs through (I see it going through the code when I debug it), but the PanelGrid component is never updated with the file preview. Interestingly enough (since I have declared the bean as session scoped), If navigate out of and then back to the page, the panel grid contains the new data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `<h:dataTable>`? Using `binding` on a session scoped bean is wrong in first place.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks. My JSF is not very strong as yet. Is that the "proper" way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I thought this way was shorter (less code in the back) than having a datatable with a datamodel that I build up in the back end. I will try that and post back

Comment: @BalusC, I have been able to get a working solution. I went about the problem differently. I first changed the logic to use a datatable instead of a panelgrid, then I set the value attribute of the datatable element to a ListDataModel in the backing bean. But then I still had the problem of deciding which columns I wanted to display at runtime, so I got queried UIViewRoot for the dataTable and set the columns on that. This works!! I still have questions though, Why is binding not advisable on a session scoped bean?

Comment: Component is specific to the view and shouldn't be shared among multiple views (browser windows/tabs on the same URL in the same session). The `binding` attribute should point to a request scoped bean.

Comment: @BalusC, so if I'm doing this from a session scoped bean, is it then better to fetch the component by ID if I want to manipulate it? because it seems to me that approach results in a tight coupling between the page and the backing bean (i.e. if the xhtml changes, I have to remember not to break the dynamic table generation in the bean). But when I try binding it, the datatable does not render. If I debug LifecycleImpl.java (as you've mentioned in a previous post), I can see that my datable is getting built up in the backing bean, but I don't know why it doesn't render. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've resolved this problem.

If there's a better way to do this, please post a better solution or let me know in the comments. Ideally, I would like to get rid of the line in the backing bean where I fetch the component by ID in order to manipulate it. I would have thought binding is for that purpose?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Backing Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dataTableTesterBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DataTableTesterBean {
    private DataTable dataTable;
    private ListDataModel<String[]> dataModel;

    public String initDataTable() {
        buildDataModel();
        buildDataTable();
        return "";
    }

    public ListDataModel<String[]> getDataModel() {
        return dataModel;
    }

    public void setDataModel(ListDataModel<String[]> dataModel) {
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }

    public DataTable getDataTable() {
        return dataTable;
    }

    public void setDataTable(DataTable dataTable) {
        //do nada
    }

    private Column buildColumn(String colTitle, String colValueExpr) {
        //add columns so the datatable knows what to display
        Column col = (Column) JsfUtil.createComponent(Column.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        UIOutput title = (UIOutput) JsfUtil.createComponent(UIOutput.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        title.setValue(colTitle);
        col.getFacets().put("header", title);
        //setup the field that will display the column data
        ValueExpression val = JsfUtil.createValueExpression(colValueExpr, Object.class);
        HtmlOutputText display = (HtmlOutputText) JsfUtil.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        display.setValueExpression("value", val);
        col.getChildren().add(display);
        return col;
    }

    private void buildDataModel() {
        //build up the data
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new String[]{"A", "123", "apples"});
        data.add(new String[]{"B", "456", "oranges"});
        data.add(new String[]{"C", "789", "bananas"});
        data.add(new String[]{"D", "987", "lemons"});
        data.add(new String[]{"E", "654", "mangoes"});
        dataModel = new ListDataModel(data);
    }

    private void buildDataTable() {
        //The following line should work, don't know why it doesn't
        //dataTable = (DataTable) JsfUtil.createComponent(DataTable.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        dataTable = (DataTable) JsfUtil.getUIComponent("frmTester:myDataTable");

        dataTable.setVar("item");

        Column abcCol = buildColumn("ABCs", "#{item[0]}");
        dataTable.getColumns().add(abcCol);

        Column numCol = buildColumn("Nums", "#{item[1]}");
        dataTable.getColumns().add(numCol);

        Column fruitCol = buildColumn("Fruits", "#{item[2]}");
        dataTable.getColumns().add(fruitCol);
    }
}
```

---

**JSF Page**

```
<h:form id="frmTester">
<h:commandButton value="Do Stuff" action="#{dataTableTesterBean.initDataTable}"/>
<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" value="#{dataTableTesterBean.dataModel}" binding="#{dataTableTesterBean.dataTable}" />
</h:form>
```

---

Comment: accepting my own answer since it's been a week since anybody answered. My solution works, I just thought there might be a better way of doing it.